# Does GMAIL security allow's the third party to take the mails without having userid and password of a person?

Tags: python, smtp, imap

Fetching the GMAIL mails through IMAP and SMTP, it requires the id and password of the person(of whom u want to fetch the mails) and the account should be less secure. Is there any other way through which i can fetch the mails of a person(without asking for his/her password).
Even GMAIL API works if the account is Less secure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If the gmail account has [two step verification enabled](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en) or if it has [disabled access for less secure applications](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer/6010255?hl=en), then you need to generate an [application password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1070457?hl=en&ref_topic=1099588) for the specific app that needs access.

Otherwise, you need to use oauth2; which is what the [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) uses.

Comment: Yeah that is the main issue two step verification and less security.
we can't ask any user to do this manually. :P

Comment: Then you have no choice.

Comment: No; the purpose of OAuth2 is to facilitate access without the password.

Comment: but the account should be less secured.. @tripleee

Comment: oauth2 has nothing to do with the less secured option; it is used universally. the less secure has to do mainly with older email clients.

Comment: The links you offered seem to be for a HTTP-oriented API, not IMAP / SMTP.

Comment: Oauth2 requires a Web browse to set up, but you can use the oauth tokens in imap and smtp.

Comment: that means any person can remove your mails who haves your id, that to  prior your permission??